# Visual Studio Online Build access denied

Tags: azure-devops

I'm very new to TFS but am using Visual Studio Team Services... which i believe are largely the same configurations and technologies.

Now its possible that VS Team Services only supports web projects but they to be the only type of project that i'm able to build.   I've tried several other (non-web) project types including the default console project but I always get a build error similar to one below....

```
C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\App1\App1\App.config: 
Access to the path 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\App1\App1' is denied.
```

I'll get a error like the one above for every file in the project.

Can someone confirm whether Visual Studio Team Services does support building other types of projects. If so, is there some special permission or additional setting in build definition that needs to be set prior to triggering build?

Comment: It should support this. How is the app.config added to the Project file? Can you post the XML from the .csproj file for it? I would guess that there is *not* a relative path, but the path you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks.   Turns out all i needed to do was to switch the build template under Build Definition->Process--> Build Process file from default to 'TfvcTemplate.12.xaml'.